# How to set hint possition when EditText is inactive

Tags: android, xamarin.android

When I have adjusted some value in my EditText that is inactive, it looks like in the following picture:
[image]

When I remove a value from the EditText in the inactive state it looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to set some property of TextInputLayer or TextInputEditText to get behaviour in the inactive state like this:
[image]

Comment: could it work now ?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Yes, I made own component which inherits from TextInputEditText. Inside of this component, I implemented a method that handling empty input. The same way as you mentioned bellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the default behavior of `TextInputEditText` with `TextInputLayout`, there's properties to set it  directly, but you can do this by making some settings, as a workaround:

you could add the `FocusChange` event to it,and when it is not in focus,set a `" "`（empty value） to it ：

```
TextInputEditText textInputEditText = FindViewById<TextInputEditText>(Resource.Id.editText);

textInputEditText.FocusChange += delegate
         {
             if (!textInputEditText.IsFocused)
             {
                 if (string.IsNullOrEmpty( textInputEditText.Text))
                 {
                     textInputEditText.Text = " ";
                 }
             }
             else
             {
                 if (textInputEditText.Text == " ")
                 {
                     textInputEditText.Text = "";
                 }
             }
         };
```

Comment: Yes, I also get this idea and this is my secondary plan. But I would like to know if exist there some solution in the XML level.

Comment: @Sobansky yeah,but I don't think there is a property that can be set directly in XML

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, you should be wrapping the edit text inside of the TextInputLayout as follows:

```
 <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:hint="@string/form_username">

     <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

 </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Make sure also that you have the material design libraries in your app's gradle build file. Hope this helps :)

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/textfield/TextInputLayout <-- link to the documentation